# Correct type of data for latitude and longtitude SSIS ETL process

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

I'm trying to convert and upload latitude and longitude data into a database through an ETL process I created where we take the source data from a .csv file and convert it to DECIMAL. Here you have an example of what the two values look like:

```
Latitude (first column): 41.896585191199556  
Longitude (second column):-87.66454238198166
```

I set the data type on the database as for:

```
Latitude DECIMAL(10,8)
Longitude DECIMAL(11,8)
```

The main problem arises when I try to convert data from file to database and then I get the message
`[Flat File Source [85]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Latitude" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".`

View of my process:

[image: Data flow]

When trying to ignore the error Latitude and Longitude values in the database are changed to NULL... The flat file encoding is 65001.
I tried doing conversions for data types: float, DECIMAL, int and nothing helped.
My questions are:

1. what data type for these above values should I use in the target database.
2. what data type should i choose on input for flat file ?
3. what data type to set for conversion (I suspect the one we will have on the database) ?

please note that some records in the file are missing the location

- view from Data:
  [image: Data view]
- view from Data Conversion:
  [image: Data Conversion view]

**UPDATE**

When FastParse is run I receive an error message as below:
[image]

What data type should I choose in this case ? I set everything up as @billinkc suggested. When I set an integer, for example DT_I4, it results in NULL and the same error as before (in this message there is no possibility to select some data type for the value of Latitude, i.e. DECIMAL or STRING).

Comment: How have you defined the columns in the Flat File Connection Manager. By default, it will be string. You mention 65001 file encoding - what Windows Locale are you in (if not US centric)?

Comment: @billinkc I defined the columns with the type as it appears in the database, for example for Latitude decimal. Windows is located in center Europe

Answer (score 0):

You need `DECIMAL(11,8)`.  That has three digits *before* the decimal place and either digits *after*.

The conversion failure is no doubt happening when you have longitudes above 100 or less than -100.

Comment: I set DECIMAL(11,8) as you recommended but still get the same error and NULL values once ignored

Comment: @lechsollagos . . . In that case, you might need to import it as a string and see what is actually in the column.

Comment: It's terryfing but I have tried with 26th Flat File Managers with tons of combination and no effect... after 4 hours I'm starting to doubt that this will work.. I tried this solution with String but still same error

Answer (score 0):

The error reported indicates the failure point is the Flat File Source

> [Flat File Source [85]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Latitude" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

<s>I'm on a US locale machine so you *could* be running into issues with the decimal separator. If that's the case, then in your Flat File Source, right click and select Show Advanced Editor. Go to Input and Output Properties, and under the Flat File Source Output, expand Output Columns and for each column that is a floating point number, check the `FastParse` option.</s>

If that works, great, you have a valid Flat File Source.

I was able to get this working two different ways. I defined two Flat File Connection Managers in my package: `FFCM Dec` and `FFCM String` While I prefer to minimize the number of operations and transforms I apply to my packages, declaring the data types as strings can help you get past the hurdle of "I can't even get my data flow to start because of bad data"

### Source data

I created a CSV saved as UTF-8

```
Latitude,Longitude
41.896585191199556,-87.66454238198166
```

### FFCM Dec

I configured a standard CSV

[image]

I defined my columns with the `DataType` of `DT_DECIMAL`

[image]

### FFCM String

Front page is the same but on the columns in the Advanced section, I left the data type as DT_WSTR with a length of 50

[image]

At this point, we've defined the basic properties of how the source data is structured.

### Destination

I went with consistency on the size for the destination. You're not going to save anything by using 10 vs 11 and I'm too lazy to look up the allowable domain for lat/long numbers

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SO_65909630 
(
    [Latitude] decimal(18,15)
,   [Longitude] decimal(18,15)
)
```

### Data Flow

I need to run but you either use the correctly typed data when you bring it in (DFT DEC) or you transform it.

[image]

The blanks I see in your source data will likely need to be dealt with (either you have a column that needed to be escaped or there is no data - which will cause the data conversion to fail so I'd advocate this approach

[image]

Row counts are there just to provide a place to put a data viewer while I was building the answer

### What data type should I use for lat and long

Decimal is an exact data type so it will store the *exact* value you supply. When used it takes the form of `decimal(scale, precision)`. Before my current role, I had never used any other data type for non-whole numbers.

Books On Line on decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Scale

> The maximum total number of decimal digits to be stored. This number includes both the left and the right sides of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

Precision

> The number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p, and can only be specified if precision is specified. The default scale is 0 and so 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

```
Precision   Storage bytes

1 - 9           5
10-19           9
20-28          13
29-38          17
```

For the table I defined above, it will cost us 18 bytes (2 * 9) for each lat/long to store.

But let's look at the actual domain for latitude and longitude (on Earth) This magnificent answer on GIS.se is printed out and hangs from my work monitor https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude

Pasting the relevant bits here

- The **sixth decimal place** is worth up to 0.11 m: you can use this for laying out structures in detail, for designing landscapes, building roads.  It should be more than good enough for tracking movements of glaciers and rivers.  This can be achieved by taking painstaking measures with GPS, such as differentially corrected GPS.
- The **seventh decimal place** is worth up to 11 mm: this is good for much surveying and is near the limit of what GPS-based techniques can achieve.
- The **eighth decimal place** is worth up to 1.1 mm: this is good for charting motions of tectonic plates and movements of volcanoes.  Permanent, corrected, constantly-running GPS base stations might be able to achieve this level of accuracy.
- The **ninth decimal place** is worth up to 110 microns: we are getting into the range of microscopy.  For almost any conceivable application with earth positions, this is overkill and will be more precise than the accuracy of any surveying device.
- **Ten or more decimal places** indicates a computer or calculator was used and that no attention was paid to the fact that the extra decimals are useless.  Be careful, because unless you are the one reading these numbers off the device, this can indicate low quality processing!

Your input values show more than 10 digits of precision so I'm guessing it's a calculated value and not a "true observation". That's good, that gives us more wiggle room to work with.

Why, we could dial that decimal declaration down the following for half<sup>*</sup> the storage cost of the first one

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SO_65909630_alt
(
    [Latitude] decimal(8,5)
,   [Longitude] decimal(8,5)
);
```

Well that's good, we've stored the "same" data at lower the cost. Maybe your use case is just "where are my stores" and even if you're Walmart with under 12000 stores, who cares? That's a trivial cost. But if you need to also store the coordinates of their customers, the storage cost per record *might* start to matter. Or use Amazon or Alibaba or whatever very large consumer retailer exists when you read this.

In my work, I deal with meteorological data and it comes in all shapes and sizes but a common source for me is [Stage IV data](https://www.emc.ncep.noaa.gov/mmb/ylin/pcpanl/stage4/) It's *just* hourly rainfall amounts across the contiguous US. So 24 readings per coordinate, per day. Coordinate system is 1121 x 881 (987,601 points) so expressing hourly rainfall in the US for a day is 23,702,424 rows. The difference between 18 bytes versus 10 bytes can quickly become apparent given that Stage IV data is available back to 2008.

We actually use a [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (or real) to store latitude and longitude values because it saves us a 2 bytes per coordinate.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SO_65909630_float
(
    [Latitude] float(24)
,   [Longitude] float(24)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.SO_65909630_alt
(
    Latitude
,   Longitude
)
SELECT * FROM dbo.SO_65909630 AS S
```

Now, this has caused me pain because I can't use an exact filter in queries because of the fun of floating point numbers.

My decimal typed table has this in it

```
41.89659    -87.66454
```

And my floating type table has this in it

```
41.89658    -87.66454
```

Did you notice the change to the last digit in Latitude? 8 not 9 as the decimal table has but either way, it doesn't matter

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SO_65909630_float AS S WHERE S.Latitude = 41.89658
```

This won't find a row because of floating point rounding exact match nonsense. Instead, your queries become very tight range queries, like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SO_65909630_float AS S WHERE S.Latitude >= (41.89658 - .00005) AND S.Latitude <= (41.89658 + .00005)
```

where `.00005` is a value that you'll have to experiment with given your data to find out how much you need to adjust the numbers to find it again.

Finally, for what it's worth, if you convert lat and long into the Geography [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) it's going to coerce the input data type to float as it is.

Comment: thank you so much for this clarificaiton - now I understand some more than before regarding this topic. One more request from my end - could you please take a look on the latest update in answer ? I faced next issue with this flat file

Comment: FastParse was just a thought but as the error message says, it's incompatible with the data type. If you define as string or decimal in the flat file source as I show here, the package works. Use the same sample data and make a tiny reproduction package (either define the column as string in the flat file connection manager and do the conversion in the package or define the type as decimal in the flat file connection manager). If that works, then you slowly increase the complexity until you determine what is causing your full package to fail